# Is there any way to input into a boolean field in the Pycharm database window?

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to type a row of data into the Pycharm database window. My DB is SQLite. However, I can't find a way to type a value into a boolean column (in the case below it's the current_record_fg column).

[image]

Is there any way for me to type a value into that boolean field? (I've tried right clicking, etc. Nothing seems to work). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit these in the PyCharm Database tools, but SQLite Studio make this an easy process.  You can copy paste from excel (or any other tab delineated format).  Remember that in SQLite Boolean data is stored as a 0 for false and 1 for true. Official site: https://sqlitestudio.pl/

Comment: Thank you, Sherd but I was hoping to stay within the Pycharm environment.

Comment: Sure, though FYI for you, SQLite Studio is free (open source) and very lightweight.